# How to make scrollbars appear in a wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel which has no widgets but only a straight line?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, scrollbar

I create a wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel. I insert it in its parent panel inside a vertical box sizer. Parent panel's size is width=500, height=500.

Then,  in ScrolledPanel, I draw a vertical line with a height of 1000.
When I run the app, scrollbars are not displayed on ScrolledPanel. I just see my vertical line with a height of 500, because height of parent panel is 500.
There are no widgets in scrolledpanel or parent panel.

Why doesn't the vertical scrollbar appear, so that I can scroll down and see the rest of that vertical line? How do I make it appear?

I even try to set the height of ScrolledPanel to 1000 after I draw the vertical line, but it doesn't work either, something like:

this doesn't work:

```
create_parent_panel_with_height_500()
create_scrolled_panel()
put_scrolled_panel_on_parent_panel_and_set_sizer()
push_a_button_to_draw_the_vertical_line_with_height_1000()
update_and_refresh_scrolled_panel()
```

this doesn't work either:

```
create_parent_panel_with_height_500()
create_scrolled_panel()
put_scrolled_panel_on_parent_panel_and_set_sizer()
push_a_button_to_draw_the_vertical_line_with_height_1000()
set_scrolled_panels_height_to_1000()
update_and_refresh_scrolled_panel()
```

In both methods, scrollbars don't appear after the vertical line is drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have any widgets on the panel then a `ScrolledPanel` is not the best choice since it bases the virtual and physical sizes of the window on the space needed by the sizer.  Using a `wx.ScrolledWindow` would be a better choice, as you can then control the virtual size yourself.

If you are stuck with the `ScrolledPanel` for some reason, it is still doable.  You should just need to create a sizer, and add a spacer to it that reserves enough space for your drawing, and assign the sizer to the panel.  There is some code in the `ScrolledPanel` that expects to have at least one child widget that accepts the focus, but that could probably be dealt with in a derived class if there are any issues from that.

Comment: Sir, why doesn't `ScrolledPanel.SetSize((0,1000))` work, why doesn't it increase the height of inside-panel to 1000? After this statement, I also do ScrolledPanel.Refresh() and ScrolledPanel.Update(), but no luck.

Comment: First, because size and virtual size are different.  The scrollbars are enabled  only when the virtual size is larger than the size.  Second, because a ScrolledPanel uses the sizer to determine the virtual size, if you set it then it will only be reset at some time by the ScrolledPanel, which is why I suggested to use wx.ScrolledWindow instead.  Take a look at the ScrolledWindow sample in the demo for example code.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not pasted any 'real' code, it's difficult to know what you are doing wrong.
Perhaps this will help:

```
#!/bin/env python
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as SP
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, - 1, "Frame", size=(300, 300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, - 1)
        self.scrolledPanel = AScrollPanel(panel)
        panel.Show()

class AScrollPanel(SP.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        SP.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, -1, size=(200, 100))
        self.parent = parent
        self.Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.Sizer)
        self.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=True, scroll_y=True, scrollToTop=False)
        self.ATop = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Top of Line")
        self.ALine = wx.StaticLine(self, -1, size=(30,1000),style=wx.LI_VERTICAL)
        self.ABottom = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Bottom of Line")
        self.Sizer.Add(self.ATop)
        self.Sizer.Add(self.ALine)
        self.Sizer.Add(self.ABottom)
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```